# Get specific value in join three table by laravel eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
Mail_Settings_Line_types table
 id
 mail_line_type
```

where mail_line_type could have values as "body" "subject" "greeting"

```
Mail_Settings_Details table
  id
  mail_line
  mail_line_type_id
  mail_id
```

where **mail_line** could have **"Dear {}}"** which will link up with "greeting" above

```
Mail_Settings table
 id
 mail_type
```

**mail_type** called have **"New Email 1", "New email 2"** etc

MY MODELS:

**MailSetting**

```
public function mail_setting_details(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\MailSettingDetail','MailSettingsTypeID','id' );
    }
```

**MailSettingDetail**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'MailSettingsLineTypeID','MailSettingsTypeID','mail_line'

   public function mail_setting_line_type(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\MailSettingLineType','id','MailSettingsLineTypeID'    );
    }

    public function mail_setting(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\MailSetting','id','MailSettingsTypeID'    );
    }
```

**MailSettingLineType**

```
'mail_line_type'

public function mail_setting_details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\MailSettingDetail','MailSettingsLineTypeID','id' );
}
```

In my controller I am calling to get a particular mail template:

```
$mail_setting = MailSetting::where('mail_type', 'New Email 2')->first();
```

I want to get the value for Mail_Settings_Details.mail_line where Mail_Settings_Line_types.mail_line_type is "subject", "or "body" etc

Sample output I want is "This is a test subject" if I ant  to get "subject".